# Suppressing audio when page loads; User Scripts, Timing Issue

Tags: javascript, userscripts

A web page loads along with its attendant javascript.  The scripts run, loading audio and then playing the audio (2 secs duration).  I want to suppress the audio in my browser.  I do not control the web page, therefore I thought to use a User Script to override the page's javascript.

However, if I write a User Script to (say) nullify the pointer to the sound-player, it's too late: the audio has already begun playing.  If instead I use `@run-at document-start` to ensure that I run early, the pointer I need to overwrite does not yet exist.

In other words,

```
window.app.soundplayer = function(){};
```

Needs to run after the `soundplayer` variable exists, but before it is called in the page's javascript.

I could try and run a function every few milliseconds, but that seems extremely ugly and unreliable.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You could try event delegation and listen for the .play perhaps?
`$(document).on("play","audio",function() { $(this).remove() })`

Comment: That may work, but I think would kill **all** audio on the page rather than just the one function I'm targeting.  How about blocking the download of the sound file itself?  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just be more specific: "audio.annoying” - you did not tell use it is one SPECIFIC audio you want to get rid of and keep the rest